# openshift php file not found ( same syntax in localhost )

Tags: php, nginx, openshift

The openshift I'm using is a DIY catridge with nginx + php 5.5.8 + phalcon 1.2.4

I have a directory structure as below

```
website
    public
       index.php
    app
       config
           config.php
           loader.php
           routes.php
           services.php
```

the problem is in my `public/index.php` i do

```
try {
    /**
     * Read the configuration
     */
    if (file_exists(__DIR__ . "/../app/config/config.php"))
    {
        $config = include __DIR__ . "/../app/config/config.php"; 
    }else{
        throw new Exception("Failed to include 'config.php'");
    }
```

and it failed

```
Failed to include 'config.php'
#0 {main}
```

Is this something to do with openshift? cause I'm doing it correct in my localhost(although it is in apache for localhost) The script should load the config.php

(changed from is_file to file_exist as it make more sense)

Comment: try something like file_exists(__DIR__ . "/../app/config/config.php); if it returns true the we can refine the syntax otherwise there might be a problem with the directory structure which we will try to fix

Comment: changed to file exists for making more sense. The problem is the file do exist, just not make sense to me.

Comment: what does file_exists() return. If it returns true let me know. Then I might know the solution

Comment: It return with false. Just git push it for a double confirm

Comment: Instead of try catch let the actual exception bubble up. For instance do store the value returned by file_exists() in a variable and then echo that value. Will give U a better idea.

Comment: And what does __DIR__ returns if we echo it.

Comment: file_exist value is bool(false);

Comment: dir is `/var/lib/openshift/52d10***************0040/app-root/runtime/repo/website/public`

Comment: This is a dynamic url being generated by the openshift. Actually I am also using openshift (codeigniter based application) referencing files never became a problem.

Comment: You could do one thing however and that is exploring the whole directory structure yourself by some SSH client. I use winpcap for windows 7". Works Great. You will however need a public private key set

Comment: Okay I think I've found the problem after sshed into openshift with git bash, The config folder do exist however there is no config.php inside. strange as I have it in my local repo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

openshift does not deny the usage of the config.php file name, make sure you have added it into your git repository and that it is not ignored by any .gitignore files.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the file exists? Also, check out if the parent directory has "+x". Quoted from PHP manual (http://php.net/is_file):

> Note that is_file() returns false if the parent directory doesn't have
>   +x set for you; this make sense, but other functions such as readdir() don't seem to have this limitation. The end result is that you can
>   loop through a directory's files but is_file() will always fail.

Comment: file_exists() can also be used in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Just found the problem that althought my local repo has above file but not config.php .

Probability 1: Probably because openshift deny the usage of config.php file name

Probability 2: Something bug happened when doing git push

Now dueling with another bug however this bug has been settled

Comment: openshift does not deny the usage of the config.php file name, make sure you have added it into your git repository and that it is not ignored by any .gitignore files.

Comment: true my gitignore file is the problem!